# Update CollectionView cells that are not selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I have a CollectionView that allows a user to touch a cell and it will change the border color. However, I only want one cell to be selected at a time. How can I edit this code so that the cell at indexpath is updated with the border color and previously selected cell is reset?

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.user["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row]

        do {
           try self.user.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
```

Thanks!

UPDATE

```
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell
        var previouslySelectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
        if previouslySelectedIndexPath != nil {
            let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(previouslySelectedIndexPath!) as! AvatarViewCell
            previousCell.layer.borderWidth = 0
            previousCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        }

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have an instance variable (add at the beginning of your class file) to store the previously selected cell

```
var previouslySelectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

Then every time a new cell is selected, you first remove the border from the previously selected cell and then add the border to the newly selected cell

```
if previouslySelectedIndexPath != nil {
    let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(previouslySelectedIndexPath!) as! AvatarViewCell
    previousCell.borderWidth = 0
}
let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell
cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
previouslySelectedIndexPath = indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated the code but it doesn't seem to work. I updated my question. Do I need to set previouslySelectedIndexPath somewhere else?

Comment: I noticed in your code that you're putting the `previouslySelectedIndexPath` declaration inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, this is wrong, it should be declared at the top of your class.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Here's an example using a vanilla UICollectionViewCell:

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I set cell to? It would have to be different than `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell` right?

Comment: I edited my answer above to include sample code. In your case, yes, it would be `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell`.

Comment: This is the best answer as it elegantly use the frameworks without adding needless state tracking.